# How can I set up apache to serve from my ~/Web folder instead of /var/www/html?

Tags: apache

I use Fedora 21. I'd like to be able to develop in ~/Web, that is, /home/me/Web, instead of /var/www/html, since I have a /home partition with lots of free space, but a / partition with not so much free space. Is there a way to do that relatively easily?

Answer (score 0):

Note: You're going to need root permissions for most of these commands.

First, edit this text file with the text editor of your choice:

```
$ vim /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

Replace `/var/www/html` with the path of your choice.

Then, restart the server:

```
$ service apache2 restart
```

It still might not work, and this is because Apache requires that all parent directories have the appropriate permissions (via `chmod`) for it to work. You have two options at this point:

1. `chmod a+rw` (all users, read and write) all the parent directories leading to your `~` directory. **This is, for obvious reasons, not recommended.**
2. Give up and resign to using a separate folder such as `/var/www`. This is what I usually do. You could, however, create a symlink in your home directory from `~/Web` to `/var/www/html` if you would like.

   ```
   ~$ ln -s /var/www/html Web
   ```

   This would achieve almost exactly the same result, and **is the method that I would recommend.**

Comment: I don't have an `/etc/apache2` directory. I think in Fedora it's `httpd` something, but `locate 000-default.conf` doesn't return anything.

Comment: @Jono Hmm. Sorry, I'm running Ubuntu right now, but it could possibly be in `/etc/httpd/conf.d`. Try looking in there, or running something like `grep "/var/www/html" /etc/httpd`.